# What is "Sprinter" in the Netherlands?

Tags: public-transport, netherlands, local-knowledge

I am trying to avoid construction traffic on Friday morning drive and found a route marked "Sprinter".  What does sprinter mean / imply in the Netherlands?  Is it a bus?  Is it not for driving?

[image]

Comment: You selected public transit as a mode of transportation. It is not a driving route.

Comment: For your convenience, [Sprinter light train on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NS_Sprinter_Lighttrain).

Comment: If you use the "depart at" or "arrive by" options in Google Maps for the expected time of your journey, it will adjust its suggestions and time estimates based on historical traffic data. This isn't a complete substitute for local knowledge, but will help give you a more specific idea of typical conditions at the time you'll be traveling.

Comment: Traffic if relatively low on Friday mornings, most main roads will be without traffic jams, just avoid the one(s) they are working on and google will likely give a 'road being worked on' icon for that.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit as it changed the question to a completely different one, making all answers off the 'new main point' of the question. See my comment above this for travel advice.

Comment: Following on from @Willeke, if you have a new question, please ask a new question, even if it follows on from this one, rather than changing the nature of this question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

'Sprinter' is the name for the train service that stops at each station.

The alternative are the 'Intercity' services that only stop at limited stations.

The route you have selected first uses the sprinter train from Schiphol Airport station to Naarden Bussum station, there you change onto bus line 101 which will drop you off at the AmersfoortseStraatweg in Naarden. That is why, as Willeke commented, you (also) see the bus icons and the route following the roads (the small final leg):

[image]

Comment: The name used to be "stoptrein", but apparently that didn't sound flashy enough.

Comment: Interesting. In Germany, sprinters are very fast ICEs between large metropoles with none or very few stops.  For example Berlin - Frankfurt with just one stop in Hannover.

Comment: The name came into use when NS ordered trainsets designed to accelerate quickly, to reduce travel times on routes where stations are close together.

Comment: @sweber The notion is that they do short "sprints" rather than long runs. They are lighter and reach the top speed (which is only 130-160 anyway) faster than IC trains and also have more doors per unit of length to load/unload faster.

Comment: @MrLister The name is still "Stoptrein". Only specific trains and routes are called sprinter, usually near the "randstad". Also, only the transporter "NS" actually uses the term sprinter, the others still use "stoptrein" or the localized "boemel"

Comment: @MXD Actually, NS introduced the name *Sprinter* in that way but as of 2013 it does not use the word *stoptrein* anymore. And given its large role, it makes more sense to write that only other transporters call such trains anything else than *Sprinter*.

Comment: @MXD While originally the name for a specific type of train, the NS actually uses the word sprinter (and has been since 2013) for all stoptreinen, not just in the randstad.. But it's true, other transport companies still use stoptrein.

Comment: @sweber there is also another Sprinter to FFM that goes the southern route and stops in Halle and Erfurt. ;)

Comment: @MXD Is the word *boemel* used in official context anywhere?  I only know it as a colloquialism.

Comment: @gerrit no, it is indeed a colloquialism. All though train personal often refer to it using this colloquialism. This happens especially often in rural areas.

Answer (score 9):

Notice the icons on the Google Maps route.

[image: Google car icon] Means a car route

[image: Google bus icon] Means a bus journey

[image: Google Tram Icon] Means a tram journey

[image: Google Train Icon] Means a train journey

Slightly confusingly, the icons shown on the route are suggesting that this will be a bus journey, transferring to another bus. However, if you look in the directions pane on the left (on desktop, may be elsewhere on mobile) you will see the correct icons there. If you do not wish to be shown public transport options, then change along the tabs in directions from "any directions" (the arrow sign, which will show the fastest options in all modes) to the little icon of the car. Equally, if you only want public transport, there's a picture of a train. Cycling, walking and flight routes are also available.

Comment: Going from the Icons, I'd say this on the map is a bus service, but certainly no car journey.

Comment: @Willeke if you repeat the OP's search (roughly) it says its a train then bus, and the change is at the train station. https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Amsterdam+Airport+Schiphol,+Evert+van+de+Beekstraat+202,+1118+CP+Schiphol,+Netherlands/Amersfoortsestraatweg,+Netherlands/@52.3009962,5.0581007,13z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c5e134e0fd162d:0xc7d51583f1cef188!2m2!1d4.7682744!2d52.3105386!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c614903d87bca9:0x572645b4dc691380!2m2!1d5.1858031!2d52.278834!5i2

Comment: Yes, I get that, but in the map he shows in the OP, there is ONLY the bus icon. And that I can not get. Might have been a time of day thing.

Comment: @Willeke I get the same thing drawn on the map (Bus->Bus icon). In the actual instructions of how to do it, I get Train -> Bus. I figure it's a bug.

Answer (score 3):

It probably suggests the use of a train (sprinter) because the A1 is currently being constructed. There's a lot of traffic there usually and on some days it's closed down completely.

Comment: If travelling Friday 9:30AM would I be wise to use route 3?  (new routes posted to original question)

Comment: would I be better of using route-3 and not route-1?

Comment: @gatorback do you have internet before departure? You can check traffic before you go if you do. My guess is 9:30 AM it would be fine to take route 1 or 2. I've been driving the same route weekly (coincidentally to one street next to your destination) and have not had much trouble after 9:30.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed a train stopping at all stations and speedy sprints between them.
It is marked as an alternative because by car travel time is - much - longer in rush-hours on that particular route. When travelling week-days between 7:00 and 9:30 and 16:30 and 19:00 local time it is much faster,as much as 200%. Trade-off time and cost. It's like the M1 in England, that bad, to travel by car.

Comment: On Friday morning, the route is definitely faster by car.